# Why must API keys be kept private?

Tags: api, security, risk

I have worked with public API's in only one small project, but I recently learned that if one were to distribute a project with API keys inside this is a security risk.

So I have two questions:

- What does an API key contain that would pose a security risk?
- How does one create an application that makes use of public API's and
  distribute that application without posing a security risk?

Surely if someone can reverse engineer the application, they could extract any API keys that are present.

Comment: if I have your Facebook API key, I can post to Facebook under your name, delete your account, reset your password, etc.

Comment: The concept of a *credential* (or more formally, a [capability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capability-based_security)) may be useful.

Comment: An API key is just a different form of username+password. Surely you know why those should be kept private…

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what the API key does. However, if the API key is giving you access to something or controlling your access to something, why would you want other people to piggyback on the resources that you have access to? You wouldn't.

Think about it this way. I own a service and you are a user of it, perhaps even a paying customer. I give you an API key based on an agreed upon level of service (perhaps API calls per unit of time). If this API key was public, other people could use it to pretend to be you and use up your limited API calls.

That's probably the least concerning situation. Sharing of API keys becomes more of a concern if the API key authenticates someone for access to a subset of data.

The methods of protecting API keys depends on the technology that you are using. When developing web or mobile applications, for example, you can help protect your API keys by ensuring they don't end up on the client (the web browser or the mobile device). Instead, they can remain on the servers used by the client. The client can authenticate against the services which can then make appropriate calls. Depending on the environment, the API keys can even be encrypted as they are stored in different environments.

Comment: I wouldn't call that an "API key". That's an account key. An API key is a key that lets an application you publish and distribute to third parties make use of a service, and it is **not** an access control method, but rather a weak source of accountability, so that if your application does something the API provider does not like, they can pull its access and hurt your reputation/business. The assumption is that third parties would not extract and reuse your API key in sufficient volume that their behavior would be misattributed to your application.

Comment: So how is this different from an account key? Your company created an account and received an API key _forvthat account_.

Comment: In some cases its simply impossible to protect your API key like for map tile apis since this has to be on the frontend. These API keys will never have access to account controls and sometimes have a way to limit the allowed domains so if someone tries to use it on their website the referer data will cause it to not work.

Answer (score 8):

There are different kinds of API keys. Some API keys are designed to be made public, they're usually called something like publishable keys, and are designed to be sent out to users in web pages or application bundles. This type of API keys aren't intended for authentication, but rather simple identification. There are few use cases where this is reasonable, but generally this may be fine for low security application or if you have your security somewhere else.

Most API keys though, are authentication secret. The value of the resource it's protecting varies. Even if the API itself is only displaying publicly available data and there's no private resources, sometimes the API provider requires your to use an API key so that they can enforce rate limiting, the risk to you if your API key leaked and someone used your API key is that your application may effectively be denied service because your reached your designated limit. If this is a paid API, you may incur unnecessary costs if others used your API key.

Other times, the API key is meant as a token for your authorization that the request should be performed by the service provider. If you leak your API key, then you would no longer be in control of the protected resource as your user would be able to instruct the archive provider directly, bypassing your intended business logic.

Answer (score 6):

Think about it this way, most people are not in the habit of distributing keys to their private property (house, cars, etc.).  Why?  ***Because those keys protect critical assets, and prevent people you don't know from stealing things.***  You can think of the API key as the API password.  Anything your application is authorized to do with the API, someone else can do if they steal your credentials.

The concept is no different for digital keys, the only challenge is that it is more difficult to secure them or handle the keys safely.  It's also more common to provide separate keys for each client of the API.  This not only enables administrating different subscription levels or permission sets for each client, but it also enables authoritative audit logs where the holder of the API keys cannot [*repudiate*](https://www.cryptomathic.com/products/authentication-signing/digital-signatures-faqs/what-is-non-repudiation) the actions logged.

If we are talking OAuth 2, the most common API access control mechanism, then there are two keys to worry about:

- The client key: identifies your application to the API provider
- The secret key: authenticates you so that no-one can impersonate you

The combination of keys are critical, which is why OAuth mandates TLS for exchanging the keys.  The client key by itself is less critical of a resource to protect, but it's not something you should advertise.  The secret key is the one you have to go through extra measures to protect.

The bottom line is that any key should be carefully protected.  There's enough people out there who are looking to abuse weaknesses in security to get what they want.  Even small insignificant sites are good targets if they can find something there that they can use to impersonate a user elsewhere.

---

As to your second question, there is a reason why OAuth 2 has become an industry standard.  It's well defined, and there are supporting libraries in just about every programming language to work with it.  It's best not to re-invent the wheel without a very good reason, particularly when there is so much support for the existing standard.

Please note: reverse engineering the logic of the application doesn't automatically grant access to the data it manages.  If you design your application correctly, you won't necessarily have the information required to steal other people's keys.

Answer (score 2):

> I have worked with public API's in only one small project, but I recently learned that if one were to distribute a project with API keys inside this is a security risk.

Seriously speaking I want to congrats you for already know this so earlier in your career, because believe you or not, a lot of senior developers are still misinformed or unaware of the security implications for distributing an API key.

One of the main causes that leads to all this confusion about API keys, that many don't even realize, is that a developer needs to be aware about the difference between **WHAT** and **WHO** is accessing the API server.

## The Difference Between WHO and WHAT is Accessing the API Server

To better understand the differences between the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are accessing an API server, let’s use this picture:

[image: Man in the Middle Attack]

The Intended Communication Channel represents the mobile app being used as you expected, by a legit user without any malicious intentions, using an untampered version of the mobile app, and communicating directly with the API server without being man in the middle attacked.

The actual channel may represent several different scenarios, like a legit user with malicious intentions that may be using a repackaged version of the mobile app, a hacker using the genuine version of the mobile app, while man in the middle attacking it, to understand how the communication between the mobile app and the API server is being done in order to be able to automate attacks against your API. Many other scenarios are possible, but we will not enumerate each one here.

I hope that by now you may already have a clue why the **WHO** and the **WHAT** are not the same, but if not it will become clear in a moment.

The **WHO** is the user of the mobile app that we can authenticate, authorize and identify in several ways, like using OpenID Connect or OAUTH2 flows.

> [OAUTH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth)
>
> Generally, OAuth provides to clients a "secure delegated access" to server resources on behalf of a resource owner. It specifies a process for resource owners to authorize third-party access to their server resources without sharing their credentials. Designed specifically to work with Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), OAuth essentially allows access tokens to be issued to third-party clients by an authorization server, with the approval of the resource owner. The third party then uses the access token to access the protected resources hosted by the resource server.
>
> [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/connect/)
>
> OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer on top of the OAuth 2.0 protocol. It allows Clients to verify the identity of the End-User based on the authentication performed by an Authorization Server, as well as to obtain basic profile information about the End-User in an interoperable and REST-like manner.

While user authentication may let the API server know **WHO** is using the API, it cannot guarantee that the requests have originated from **WHAT** you expect, the original version of the mobile app.

Now we need a way to identify **WHAT** is calling the API server, and here things become more tricky than most developers may think. The **WHAT** is the thing making the request to the API server. Is it really a genuine instance of the mobile app, or is a bot, an automated script or an attacker manually poking around with the API server, using a tool like Postman?

For your surprise you may end up discovering that It can be one of the legit users using a repackaged version of the mobile app or an automated script that is trying to gamify and take advantage of the service provided by the application.

Well, to identify the **WHAT**, developers tend to resort to an API key that usually they hard-code in the code of their mobile app. Some developers go the extra mile and compute the key at run-time in the mobile app, thus it becomes a runtime secret as opposed to the former approach when a static secret is embedded in the code.

The above write-up was extracted from an article I wrote, entitled *WHY DOES YOUR MOBILE APP NEED AN API KEY?*, and that you can read in full [here](https://blog.approov.io/why-does-your-mobile-app-need-an-api-key), that is the first article in a series of articles about API keys.

## Reverse Engineering

> Surely if someone can reverse engineer the application, they could extract any API keys that are present.

Any secret that is stored in a web application will be easy to extract, just hit F12 in the browser or `view page source` and then search for it.

For a mobile app some may think that is much harder, but in fact is also easy, and you can take the route of reverse engineer the mobile apk, like I show in this article *[How to Extract an API Key From a Mobile App With Static Binary Analysis](https://blog.approov.io/how-to-extract-an-api-key-from-a-mobile-app-with-static-binary-analysis)*:

> Using MobSF to reverse engineer an APK for a mobile app allows us to quickly extract an API key and also gives us a huge amount of information we can use to perform further analysis that may reveal more attack vectors into the mobile app and API server. It is not uncommon to also find secrets for accessing third part services among this info or in the decompiled source code that is available to download in smali and java formats.

But my preferred method to extract an API key goes for a MitM attack, where I like to proxy the traffic between the mobile app and the API server through the [mitmproxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/) open source tool, and you can learn how to do it in a mobile app on this article I wrote *[Steal that API Key with a Man in the Middle Attack](https://blog.approov.io/steal-that-api-key-with-a-man-in-the-middle-attack)*:

> While we can use advanced techniques, like JNI/NDK, to hide the API key in the mobile app code, it will not impede someone from performing a MitM attack in order to steal the API key. In fact a MitM attack is easy to the point that it can even be achieved by non developers.

## YOUR QUESTIONS

### Question 1

> What does an API key contain that would pose a security risk?

More often then not is not about what it contains, but what it represents, and by now you may already understand that it should be used to identify **WHAT** is connecting to your API server.

In the cases where an API key is a [JWT token](https://jwt.io/introduction/), then it may or not contain in itself sensitive information.

> JSON Web Token (JWT) is an open standard (RFC 7519) that defines a compact and self-contained way for securely transmitting information between parties as a JSON object. This information can be verified and trusted because it is digitally signed. JWTs can be signed using a secret (with the HMAC algorithm) or a public/private key pair using RSA or ECDSA.

So even if the API keys don't contain any sensitive data, they are a security risk from the moment they are used to protect access to resources, because its easy to extract them from client applications and reuse them to perform automated attacks, where the attacker is able to impersonate the API server as being the genuine application(WHAT), and genuine user(WHO).

### Question 2

> How does one create an application that makes use of public API's and distribute that application without posing a security risk?

The real truth... You can't do it in a web app, because once you release it, any sensitive date on it becomes part of the public domain, once it can be viewed by anyone that inspects the web app with the built-in browser developer tools.

Now in a mobile app you may have a possible solution, that is know by Mobile App Attestation.

#### Mobile App Attestation Explained

The role of a Mobile App Attestation solution is to guarantee at run-time that your mobile app was not tampered with, is not running in a rooted device, not being instrumented by a framework like xPosed or Frida, not being MitM attacked, and this is achieved by running an SDK in the background. The service running in the cloud will challenge the app, and based on the responses it will attest the integrity of the mobile app and device is running on, thus the SDK will never be responsible for any decisions.

[Frida](https://www.frida.re/)

> Inject your own scripts into black box processes. Hook any function, spy on crypto APIs or trace private application code, no source code needed. Edit, hit save, and instantly see the results. All without compilation steps or program restarts.

[xPosed](https://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer)

> Xposed is a framework for modules that can change the behavior of the system and apps without touching any APKs. That's great because it means that modules can work for different versions and even ROMs without any changes (as long as the original code was not changed too much). It's also easy to undo.

[MiTM Proxy](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/)

> An interactive TLS-capable intercepting HTTP proxy for penetration testers and software developers.

On successful attestation of the mobile app integrity a short time lived JWT token is issued and signed with a secret that only the API server and the Mobile App Attestation service in the cloud are aware. In the case of failure on the mobile app attestation the JWT token is signed with a secret that the API server does not know.

Now the App must sent with every API call the JWT token in the headers of the request. This will allow the API server to only serve requests when it can verify the signature and expiration time in the JWT token and refuse them when it fails the verification.

Once the secret used by the Mobile App Attestation service is not known by the mobile app, is not possible to reverse engineer it at run-time even when the App is tampered, running in a rooted device or communicating over a connection that is being the target of a Man in the Middle Attack.

The Mobile App Attestation service already exists as a SAAS solution at Approov(I work here) that provides SDKs for several platforms, including iOS, Android, React Native and others. The integration will also need a small check in the API server code to verify the JWT token issued by the cloud service. This check is necessary for the API server to be able to decide what requests to serve and what ones to deny.

## CONCLUSION

> I am a fresh computer science graduate so an explanation of this would be much appreciated.

I hope that I was able to answer your questions in a easy way, and that by now you clearly understand the difference between **WHAT** and **WHO** is acessing you API server, because keeping this notion alive in your memory will help you to write much more safer code, no matter if back-end or client side code.

So for web apps you cannot distribute them in a format that keeps the API key safe, therefore you will need to focus your security efforts in the API server.

For mobile apps hope still exists in the form of a Mobile App Attestation solution, that will secure both the mobile app and API server, and without having to deal with false positives.

In the end, the solution to use in order to protect your application and API server must be chosen in accordance with the value of what you are trying to protect and the legal requirements for that type of data, like the GDPR regulations in Europe.

## DO YOU WANT TO GO THE EXTRA MILE?

[OWASP Mobile Security Project - Top 10 risks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Mobile_Security_Project#Top_Ten_Mobile_Risks)

> The OWASP Mobile Security Project is a centralized resource intended to give developers and security teams the resources they need to build and maintain secure mobile applications. Through the project, our goal is to classify mobile security risks and provide developmental controls to reduce their impact or likelihood of exploitation.